# React Native, <Image> can't contain children

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to put like a logo/picture in my app. I am already using BackgroundImage so I want to put Image on top of the background. Check my code below. Please help me figure it out.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('./app/img/baky.jpeg')} style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <Image source={require('./app/img/logo.png')} style={styles.logo}> </Image>
          <Text style={styles.txt}> Hello!!!! </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inner: {
    padding: '10%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)'
  },
  logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  txt: {
    color: 'black',

  }
});
```

Comment: you have a space in-between the open and close tags. whitespace is an element (text node). make it self closing `<Image />`

Comment: @rhemon i just removed the space between the opening and closing tags and it worked! thanks!!!